# Menu tab with count

Tags: routes

I am trying to add a menu tab on the user profile page with the # of blog posts someone has made.

Ex: Blogs (3)

```
/**
* Implementation of hook_menu
*/
function menutab_followers_menu() {
$view = views_get_view( 'blogs_written' ); 
$view->execute(); 
$count = count( $view->result ); 
    $items['user/%user/blogs'] = array(
        'title' => t('Blogs @count', array('@count' => $count)),
        'page callback' => 'menutab_blogs_linkspage',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
        );        
    return $items;
}
```

For some reason it won't use the contextual filter. It displays Blogs (0) instead of Blogs (3) I have it set the views contextual filter to raw value, path 2, and use url alias. Ex: mywebsite.com/users/admin

If I insert the view in the profile page using Display Suite, it works fine, it displays all 3 items on the page. Also, if I set the contextual filter to a fix value and type "Admin" it displays Blogs (3) on the menu tab. But I don't want that, since it would display that to every user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "title callback" menu property instead of "title", and then use a function to generate the title. Before executing the view, set the argument as shown in the example below.

```
function menutab_followers_menu() {
    $items = array();
    $items['user/%user/blogs'] = array(
        'title callback' => 'menutab_followers_blogs_title_callback',
        'title arguments' => array(1),
        'page callback' => 'menutab_blogs_linkspage',
        'page arguments' => array(1),
        'access callback' => TRUE,
        'type' => MENU_LOCAL_TASK,
    );        
    return $items;
}

function menutab_followers_blogs_title_callback($account) {
    $view = views_get_view('blogs_written');
    $view->set_arguments(array($account->uid));
    $view->execute(); 
    $count = count($view->result);
    return t('Blogs @count', array('@count' => $count));
}
```

Also, instead of executing the view to get the count, a better approach would be to use a simple database query. An example would be:

```
$count = db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM node WHERE uid = :uid AND type = :type", array(':uid' => $account->uid, ':type' => 'blog'))->fetchField();
```

Comment: Do you know how to add html inside the t function? I want to add a <br> tag before the @count. I tried adding an echo"<br>" before the count, but it doesn't work it just outputs it as Blogs echo"<br>" 3 on the tab tittle.

Comment: t() should allow <br> in the text without using echo. It's likely that Drupal menu tabs can't have new lines by default. There might be a theme hook you can use to add the new line, but it seems like it'll be a lot of work for a small change.

Comment: yeah, even without the echo it doesn't work, it just outputs it as <br>3. I'll look into the theme hook.

Comment: not sure if you can help me with this one http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/118141/quick-tab-with-count