# How to display a Quick Tab with count?

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I'd like to display the # (count) of Blogs on my quick tab menu. Ex: Blogs (3)

I found a way to overwrite the quicktab titles using the following function with an if statement

```
   function mymodule_quicktabs_alter($quicktabs) { 
if ($quicktabs->machine_name == 'quick_tab_front_page') { 
$quicktabs->tabs = array(
  0 => array(
    'machine_name' => 'quick_tab_blogs',
    'title' => 'BLOGS',
    'weight' => '-100',
    'type' => 'qtabs',
  ),
  1 => array(
    'machine_name' => 'quick_tab_news',
    'title' => 'NEWS',
    'weight' => '-89',
    'type' => 'qtabs',
  ),
);
$quicktabs->renderer = 'quicktabs';
$quicktabs->style = 'Arrows';
$quicktabs->options = array();
}
}
```

I created a view, using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, which contains all the blog titles written by a user.

Now I need to figure-out a way to display the views' count on the quick tab title

I have tried

```
function mymodule_quicktabs_alter($quicktabs) { 
    $view = views_get_view('user_blogs');
    $view->set_arguments(array($account->uid));
    $view->execute(); 
    $count = count($view->result);
if ($quicktabs->machine_name == 'quick_tab_front_page') { 
$quicktabs->tabs = array(
  0 => array(
    'machine_name' => 'quick_tab_blogs',
    'title' => t('Blogs @count', array('@count' => $count));
```

but it gives me an error of Fatal error:  Call to a member function execute() on a non-object for the line $view = views_get_view('user_blogs');

I don't get why, I am new to php.

Comment: It is working fine for me. Check your view name that you are passing to `views_get_view()` and also from where are you getting the `$account` variable from.

Comment: Yeah the view is not loading okay, so it's probably just the view name in views_get_view().

Comment: yeah it was the view name, rookie mistake. I also got rid off $view->set_arguments(array($account->uid)); turns out I don't need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your view name that you are passing to `views_get_view()` and also from where are you getting the `$account` variable from (credits: [wolverine](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/17003/wolverine)).

And get rid off `$view->set_arguments(array($account->uid));`, you don't need it (credits: [No Sssweat](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/27710/no-sssweat)).

Comment: Brings back Drupal newbie memories.

Comment: From Drupal 4.6 or 5? The question doesn't make that clear ... yet ... Maybe it needs an updated answer for D8 also ...

Comment: `From Drupal 4.6 or 5?` hahaha, I can't imagine what those versions looked like. BTW I've been using Drupal since I joined this site.

Comment: OK, *now* this question may become a candidate for some meta-question around there to get a D8-equivalent answer ... unless of course you post your own answer like yourself ... or maybe Quick Tabs are gone in D8 (haven't checked yet) ...

Comment: No quicktabs for D8 yet. The ajax in quick tabs doesn't load js files from the node/block/view. Now days, I use my own custom/superior quicktabs.